# Gradle DSL method not found: freeCompile()

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, google-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

i want to start using gcm in my project, and i follow google instruction for that, but when i add dependencies in my build.gradle file as follow :

top level : 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

project level : 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

i have an error that says you must add firebase to your dependencies :

freeCompile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'

but after i add this to my dependencies i have another error like this :

Error:(74, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'freeCompile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'testGCM' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: freeCompile specifies the gradle dependency block that only compile firebase for the product flavor `free` , so you if have not defined a `free` product flavor then ofcourse its not going to work, in this case you can either add a new product flavor called `free` or just replace `freeCompile` with `compile` , this will compile the firebase-core lib and make it available for all product flavors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`freeCompile` specifies the gradle dependency block that only compile `firebase-core` for the product flavor free , so you if have not defined a free product flavor then ofcourse its not going to work.

In this case you can either add a new product flavor called free  like so

```
android {
    ...

    productFlavors {
        free {
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
   }

   ...
}
```

**OR** just replace freeCompile with compile , this will compile the `firebase-core` lib and make it available for all product flavors

Comment: i understand the problem, thank you for your reponse.

Comment: @user44480 If the answer resolves your issue, mark the answer please.